# Differential equation of the form $a-b\cdot v^{2} = v'$ solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am struggling to solve the differential equation $$a - b \cdot v^{2}=v'$$
If we consider the method of solving separable differential equations we can rewrite the above expression as $$\int (a-b \cdot v^{2}) \cdot dt = \int \frac{dv}{dt}\cdot dt$$ (Here the assumption was that $v$ is a function of $t$, $v(t)$).$$\implies at - b\cdot \int v^{2}\cdot dt = v $$Here is where I hit the wall and cannot seem to find my way around integrating the second power of $v(t)$ in respect to $t$. If I attempt to derive $v(t)$ by the chain rule, I end up in a loop. Is it wrong to think of separable differential equations for this particular one (even though it is in that book section)? If so, what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a - b v^{2}=v'$$
The DE is separable:
$$\int \dfrac {dv}{a-bv^2}=\int dt$$

Answer (score 2):

If you set $z=e^{u}$, then $z''=e^u(u''+u'^2)$. So if one sets $u'=bv$, $v=\frac{z'}{bz}$, then
$$
z''=bz(y'+by^2)=abz.
$$
Provided that the parameters are positive, this gives
$$
z=C_1e^{\sqrt{ab}t}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{ab}t}
$$
etc.

Comment: What do $z$ and $u$ represent here exactly? Are they variables you chose for the substitution?

Comment: Yes, they are used to construct/demonstrate the principle of the substitution. One can also go via a more general rational substitution like in my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634075/solving-riccati-differential-equation-in-general-case