# Solving Riccati differential equation in general case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebra

What I am trying to do is to solve Riccati equation:
$$y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)y+c(x)$$
I introduced new function and called it $Ri(x)$, which satisfy the following ODE:
$$y'=y^2+x$$

Is it possible that using this function I can solve Riccati eqn in general case by the terms of $Ri$ function?

My motivation is from the first order ODE:

$$y'=a(x)y+b(x)$$

The solution to this one can express by the terms of exponential function which is the solution to the following ODE

$$y'=y$$

Comment: For your motivation, the solution to $y'=a(x)y+b(x)$ can be achieved by using a particular solution to the equation $y'=a(x)y$, not $y'=y$. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here? The Ricatti equation is transformable to a linear second order ODE, to which there is no general solution, save for the use of a particular solution. Look for the paper "An Algorithm for Solving Second Order Linear Homogeneous Differential Equations" by Jerald Kovacic.

Answer (score 2):

The most general approach is to transform the equation into a linear DE or system.

Set $y=\frac{p}{q}$, then
$$
p'q-q'p=ap^2+bpq+cq^2
$$
Now separate terms with factor $p$ and terms with factor $q$. There are several solutions for that, for instance
$$
(p'-bp-cq)q=(q'+ap)p.
$$
With the introduction of the fraction one degree of freedom was gained. Setting $q'=-ap$ adds a restriction that fixes this down to a completely determined system
\begin{align}
p'&=bp+cq\\
q'&=-ap
\end{align}
This is now an almost arbitrary linear system, so it appears unlikely that a reduction to a single reference case is possible.